# Input large strings in C

Tags: c, string, memory-management

For a particular problem, I have to take string input from the user which can be of size between `1 and 10^5` . 
I used the following code

```
char *a;
a = malloc(100000*sizeof(char));
```

and inside a loop ( t refers to number of test cases )

```
while( t-- )
{
  scanf( "%d", &n );
  scanf( "%s", a );
  .....
}
```

n is the length of the string that is input by the user at run time. The problem is this is giving me "Time Limit Exceeded"

I made few changes to the above code,

```
 while( t-- )
 {
   scanf( "%d", &n );
   char a[n];
   scanf( "%s", a );
   ....
 }
```

This works perfectly fine without "TLE" . But I don't understand why. The reason for using the first code was that time would be saved since allocation of memory is done only once. Am I wrong? 
Please explain.

Comment: Who is giving the "time limit exceeding" error? I think this is not a problem with your C code but with the platform you are using.

Comment: If the string read as `a` in the second snippet really is `n` chars wide, you're under allocating by one (the terminator). Secondly, there is no "dynamic" runtime allocation in the second case. It is literally a `sub esp,n`. Were I to guess, the TLE avoidance is likely directly related to your under allocation causing an buffer overflow and overwrite of `t` setting it to the terminator (which is 0) and thus ending your loop after a single iteration.

Comment: Minor: Use `a = malloc(100000 + 1);

Comment: "Time limit exceeded" was given in www.codechef.com...

The second snippet is working perfectly fine. The first snippet is giving Time Limit Exceeded...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use malloc, the memory space will create on `HEAP`.

While in the second implementation, the memory locates on `STACK`.

As I know, stack is faster than heap.

Ref: [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap/79936#79936)

---

More over, I think declaring the `char` array outside the loop is more reasonable:

```
char a[100000] = {};

while( t-- )
 {
   scanf( "%d", &n );
   scanf( "%s", a );
   ....
 }
```

Comment: Were the `malloc` in the loop this would be a decent argument. It isn't, therefore it... isn't. It is a single-shot allocation and contributes at-worst O(1) complexity to the general algorithm.